# How do you read the 128-bit NTFS FILE_ID for a directory and/or file?

Tags: c#, c++, filesystems, ntfs

So NTFS uses a 128-bit Guid to identify files and directories, you can view this information easily enough:

```
C:\Temp>C:\Windows\System32\fsutil.exe objectid query .
Object ID :        ab3ffba83c67df118130e0cb4e9d4076
BirthVolume ID :   ca38ec6abfe0ca4baa9b54a543fdd84f
BirthObjectId ID : ab3ffba83c67df118130e0cb4e9d4076
Domain ID :        00000000000000000000000000000000
```

So this is obvious enough, but how does one retrieve this information programmatically?  Looking at the WinApi for OpenFileById(...) you should be able to get this information.  One would expect this to be done in the "[Win32 FileID API Library](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1DECC547-AB00-4963-A360-E4130EC079B8&displaylang=en)", yet the method there ([GetFileInformationByHandleEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364953(v=VS.85).aspx)) returns a [FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364226(v=VS.85).aspx) structure.  This structure defines a FileId; however, it is a LARGE_INTEGER (64bit) not the full 128 bit identifier.

I'm guessing one could use WMI for this, is that where I should turn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit of searching took me to `DeviceIoControl` and there lies the answer to your question: [`FSCTL_GET_OBJECT_ID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364570%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) returns exactly the same IDs as in your output from `fsutil`.

Anyhow, the docs for [BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363788%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) say that the 64-bit file ID already uniquely identifies a file on a given volume. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS), NTFS only supports a maximum of 2^32 files, so the 128-bit ID seems quite unnecessary.

Comment: Perfect!  (can't believe I didn't find that)  Ack - agreed that the 128bit id is overkill...

Comment: But watch out, the ReFS file system, introduced with Windows Server 2012, uses 128-bit file identifiers and the Object ID you get here is not guaranteed to be unique anymore on such volumes!

Answer (score 2):

Also please note that NOT every file does have a GUID. The GUID mechanisim is mostly used for .lnk files in order to keep the association when a the traget is moved. Only $Volume and the targets of link files have these GUIDs. Furthermore you can set them by hand.

Their advantage is that the GUID should not clash between volumes, while the file ID does.
the FILE_ID is actually 48 bit of MFT_RECORD_NUMBER and 16 bits of MFT_SEQUENCE_ID

Comment: Yea, I found that out the hard way, had to use FSCTL_CREATE_OR_GET_OBJECT_ID instead (which requires SeBackup process token). The issue with the 64bit is the same reason MS created it. I need to track movement of the file even between volumes or machines.