# Does folders in windows have IDs? or GUIDs?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, directory, file-rename

what I'm trying to do, I'm selecting a folder and copying it, I would like to avoid copying it again if the folder got renamed. so is there an ID for each folder in windows that stick with the folder till its deleted ?

C# would be perfect, or C++

Comment: Here's some research options:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482178/how-do-you-read-the-128-bit-ntfs-file-id-for-a-directory-and-or-file
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866454/unique-file-identifier-in-windows

Answer (score 4):

I think you looking somewhat like this :[Unique file ids for Windows](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=42340) - [Unique ID for files on NTFS?](http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=147151)

Windows can give a unique file indentifier using the function [GetFileInformationByHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/fileio/base/getfileinformationbyhandle.asp)

Example: (hFile is a handle to a file)

```
BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION FileInfo;

GetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, &FileInfo);
inode= FileInfo.nFileIndexLow | (FileInfo.nFileIndexHigh << 32);
volume=FileInfo.dwVolumeSerialNumber;
```

I got similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866454/unique-file-identifier-in-windows) here, that will help you implement that you are looking for..

[Unique File Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129623/unique-file-identifier) ane [Unique Folder Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132686/unique-folder-identifier)

Comment: Old post. However: this question should be marked as answer. As long as the parameters are right in the CreateFile() function, it is possible to get a unique ids for directories.

Comment: @Harald: Please check these [Getting a Folder ID C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389383/getting-a-folder-id-c-sharp?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [unique information in each file or folder NTFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425331/unique-information-in-each-file-or-folder-ntfs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score -1):

I dont think there is a way to find out for folders.

Comment: Old post... However: wrong. This is at least possible for NTFS systems since Windows XP came out.